# `openocd` configure script cannot find `libusb`

Tags: debian, configure, autotools

I'm installing OpenOCD on my Debian stretch system. When I run `./configure` it reports it cannot find libusb.

```
...
checking for LIBUSB1... no
configure: WARNING: libusb-1.x not found, trying legacy libusb-0.1 as a fallback; consider installing libusb-1.x instead
checking for LIBUSB0... no
...
```

I have the correct dependencies installed, but I still get the error.

```
libhidapi-libusb0/stable,now 0.8.0~rc1+git20140818.d17db57+dfsg-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libusb-1.0-0/stable,now 2:1.0.21-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libusb-1.0-0-dev/stable,now 2:1.0.21-1 amd64 [installed]
```

What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is unhelpful at best.

The OpenOCD `README` lists `pkg-config` as a dependency. As soon as `pkg-config` was installed, the `./configure` script was able to find `libusb-1.0-0-dev`.

```
...
checking for LIBUSB1... yes
configure: libusb-1.0 header bug workaround: LIBUSB1_CFLAGS changed to "-isystem /usr/include/libusb-1.0"
checking for LIBUSB0... no
...
```

**tl;dr**

```bsh
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

Comment: it does not work for me - it was recgnizing it for the while (two runs then nothing helps)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo aptitude install libusb-1.0-0

sudo aptitude install libhidapi-dev

sudo aptitude install libftdi-dev

./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-doxygen-pdf --enable-verbose --enable-verbose-usb-io --enable-verbose-usb-comms --enable-usbprog --enable-cmsis-dap LIBUSB1_CFLAGS="-isystem /usr/include/libusb-1.0"
```